# How to find different values within a group in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write some functions in Excel that can search for different value in groups in an excel table. And I couldn't find other similar questions that can help me with my problem.

For example:

```
Group1  0.3  
Group1  0.3  
Group1  0.2  
Group1  0.3  
Group1  0.3  
Group1  0.3  
Group2  0.5  
Group2  0.5  
Group2  0.5  
Group2  0.5  
Group2  0.5  
Group2  0.5
```

Where Group1 are not all the same, and Group2 are all 0.5. I need to write some function that can find and flag the group where the values are not all the same. My expected result is:

```
Group1  0.3 "Not all the same in this group"  
Group1  0.3 "Not all the same in this group"  
Group1  0.2 "Not all the same in this group"  
Group1  0.3 "Not all the same in this group"  
Group1  0.3 "Not all the same in this group"  
Group1  0.3 "Not all the same in this group"  
Group2  0.5 "Same"  
Group2  0.5 "Same"  
Group2  0.5 "Same"  
Group2  0.5 "Same"  
Group2  0.5 "Same"  
Group2  0.5 "Same"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,A2)=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$100,A2,B$2:B$100,B2),"Same in this group","Not all the same in this group")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))=MIN(IF(A:A=A1,B:B)),"Same","Not all the same in this group")
```

entered as an array formula (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in Row1 and copied down to suit. **Assumes** your data starts in A1 and B1.

Answer (score 0):

Without using array formula

if data starts at A1. The place following at C1 and drag below

C1 =IF(SUMIFS($B$1:$B$12,$A$1:$A$12,A2)=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,A2)*B2,"same","Not all the same in this group")

Answer (score 0):

A "Sumif" divided by a "Countif" should result in the same value as "me" if the values are all the same.   So something like this (assuming we're starting in "f11"):

```
=IF(SUMIF(F$11:F$22,F11,G$11:G$22)/COUNTIF(F$11:F$22,F11)=G11,"same","different")
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm  "-1"?  Maybe the person who voted this down didn't like the solution;  but it worked.  I'm kind of new to this .. are we supposed to vote down working solutions?